# How do I find a mongoDB document and a second one based on its id as property of the first (like an inner join)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch all mongodb documents of the model "Conversations" using mongoose in a node.js-expres setup. I did this successfully using the .find() method.  But now I want to fetch both the conversation-document as well as the respective "user"-document based on the "user" document id which is given as a property of the conversation model and i'd like to fetch them both in one object.

So a sketch: The conversation model has "_id", "sender_id" and "recipient_id". And a user has "first_name", "last_name", "email" and "password_hash".

I would like to fetch one object containing all of there properties and the _id, firstname, lastname, email and password of the user whose _id is equal to recipient_id".

But i can't seem to find this on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, in the Conversations Model, recipient_id is of type ObjectId and references User, then you can use the `populate()` function to automatically fetch the referenced Document.

Supposing your Model for the users is called User, then in the Conversations Schema, you should have :

```
recipient_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
```

Then on your find request you can add `.populate()` :

```
Conversations.find().populate("recipient_id")
```

The documents returned should contain the whole associated User document in recipient_id.

For more complex requests like this, you can also check out [$lookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Populate should be enough for your case though.